# How to exclude specific keys value from a typed object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I Have the following check logic that checks from a certain type and a component that gets props there are 2 types of props mandatory and optional

in this current case the wight props is optional the issue is the isCurrentType function returns 2 types and the el.weight is erroring out since the other type has no wight on it
I have this feeling that I am kind of over complicating the architecture.

```js
const CurrentView: React.FC<Props> = () => {

cosnt items = useAppSelector((state) => state.data.itemsFromDB);

type TypeA = {id:string; equipment:string; weight:string}
type TypeB = {id:string; equipment:string;}

export const isCurrentType = (item: any): item is TypeA | TypeB => {
  return ['typeA', 'TypeB'].includes(item?.itemType);
};

const renderItems = items.map((el) => {
if (isCurrentType(el)) {
        return (
          <Component
            id={el.id}
            equipment={el.equipment}
            weight={el.weight/*Erorr on el.weight*/ ? el.weight : undefined}       
          />
        );
}})

return(<div>{renderItems}</div>)
}
```

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing so that it's a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted as-is into a standaone IDE.  Right now it's partially pseudocode (types are not defined the way you're defining them) and also has undeclared values like `el`, and `Component`.

Comment: Do either of [these approaches](https://tsplay.dev/mL5reW) meet your needs?  If so I'll write one or both up as an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz so I used the in operator and it works perfectly. I have also edited m question to look better.

Comment: Please test it out in a standalone IDE and fix any errors that are not relevant to your question.  Declare anything undeclared.  Import anything unimported.  Fix typos.  (You've got `cosnt` in there, for example).  Reduce instead of expanding where possible.  Like the `Orig` section [here](https://tsplay.dev/w1AQOw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler will not let you access properties on a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) unless every member of the union has a known property at that key:

```
type U = { id: string, weight: string } | { id: string }
declare const u: U;
u.id.toUpperCase(); // okay
u.weight // error!   Property 'weight' does not exist on type '{ id: string; }'.
```

This is because object types in TypeScript are not *sealed* or *exact*.  It is technically possible for a value of type `{id: string}` to contain extra properties like `weight` (although [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) can complicate this):

```
const something = { id: "abc", weight: 123 }
const oops: U = something; // this is accepted
```

That compiles because `someThing` matches `{id: "abc"}`, and `weight` of type `number` doesn't invalidate that.  You were assuming that a value of type `U` either had a `string`-valued `weight` property, or was missing the `weight` properly entirely.  But the assignment `const oops: U = something` shows that this assumption is technically incorrect, and that's the problem you're running into.

---

There are a few ways around this.  You could explicitly prohibit `weight` on the second union element, by making it an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) whose value is [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type):

```
type U = { id: string, weight: string } | { id: string, weight?: never } 
// now weight is known in every member of the union --> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

declare const u: U;
u.weight // okay, string | undefined

const something = { id: "abc", weight: 123 }
const oops: U = something; // error!
```

That works now; the type of `u.weight` is known to be either `string` or `undefined`.  And the compiler catches the assignment of `something` to `oops` because now `{id: string, weight: number}` is no longer assignable to `U`.  That is, now it is correct to assume that `weight` is either present and `string`-valued, or absent (more or less).

---

A less intrusive fix is to use a [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) technique that makes the same technically-incorrect assumption as you were making.  The compiler will treat use of [the `in` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) as a way to narrow a union-typed value to those union members known to have the checked property:

```
"weight" in u ? u.weight : undefined // okay, string | undefined
```

When the `"weight" in u` check is `true`, the compiler assumes that `u.weight` is of type `string`, so it lets you evaluate `u.weight`.  This narrowing is technically unsafe, so this method is only appropriate if you can be relatively sure that the `oops` assignment will happen.  After all, that still compiles without error:

```
const something = { id: "abc", weight: 123 }
const oops: U = something; // still no error
```

But as long as your code doesn't do things like that, `in`-operator narrowing should work for you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAFATgewEYBsJiQG8AoJJAFwE8ZkBVJAXiKQEsATALiSnLReADmAGiQB3CCwEALclx59BSAL5IAPs3Zze-ActJI2EeDhBpk8DMB5IArl1oBufTYB07F+Qy0YNNAGEQKAgACgBKByQAekikDABrEEpnF3FJGSiYiDRMNABCMlRMXyokAHJU6XJSgwxoJGAMciQIAA8Wa0sKamRSwlZObm1BCKVSl2J9CysmqAxIcikdRg0BgCIQLHhVkQqZLgBGACYAZj0yKY6MGCh7Zdn5xeGMikWoVjeERBhyCDZiJQmxFAkFgCGQ6AwiywLCaJDIVBoSHoTD6mkGCmEYgklS0GOUahWuJ0O2xMgA-FxgBAAG5ZM4GIwmMxIC5NOxIpxkVzuTzeXwBIJhCLRWIJJJclKkpoi+KJETyJbqGzAQwAM34vwm50s1nuEAWSxR-S46022yxaVkSCOpwB2umsSuNyRdzm+seAmFmWyGDySH+gOB0DgiCQAElgAA5UyYURLOFdRHIwno4kWnGpxQqdSogYKrP6QzGUzmHVs+yc2xuNgeLw+LICkLhZ6y8UsstiZarXbkVasYC2JBkqs9pBcZVqjVsFti+VDXRKlUQdVUv6TDt6g2KI1o01bEmWg4nemsx3XW5MTcer2DFg4HD1DDNH1of0AoA)