# how to create a dynamic scalable typeExclude helper function that supports many different types?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a dynamic function that check if a certain element fullfils some criteria as an extension to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74883636/how-to-exclude-specific-keys-value-from-a-typed-object/74883807#74883807).

My current issue is that the `key` string becomes unavailable as key since there is no signature. How do I make the `key` dynamic for all incoming types?

```js
type TypeA = { id: string; equipment: string; weight: string }
type TypeB = { id: string; equipment: string; material: string }
type TypeC = { id: string; equipment: string; width: string } 
type TypeD = { id: string; equipment: string; old: string } 
type TypeE = { id: string; equipment: string; recent: string }
type TypeF = { id: string; equipment: string; broken: string }

type AllTypes = (TypeA | TypeB | TypeC| TypeD | TypeE | TypeF )[]
const items : AllTypes = [{ id: '11245', equipment: 'hammer', recent: 'yes' }, { id: '11335', equipment: 'screwdriver', material: 'metal' }]


const typeExclude = (key: string, el: TypeA | TypeB | TypeC| TypeD | TypeE | TypeF) => {
       return key in el ? el[key as any /*the current type at hand*/] : undefined;
};

const arr = items.map(el => typeExclude('material', el) ? 'valid':'invalid')

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Please fix your code, as well as the spelling, grammar, punctuation and capitalization in your question. As it stands, it's completely unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Code is still broken (what are those semicolons doing in `const items`?), and I think you need to re-check your playground link.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen there is a an issue with the link its sharing old code, but the current snippet here can be pasted in ts playground at your end, sorry for the mess.

Comment: Sure, we can clean up the question later, but it's still unclear what you're trying to achieve. What value do you expect `arr` to be for the given input?

Comment: May be you have to use generic here for typeExclude

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen just to state the availability of the item in an arr in this current case the output should be ['invalid', 'valid'] since material exists in the second object in arr, yet the array thing is just an example the important thing is how to make the key identifiable on all the objects, I don't want to make type guard for each object...

Comment: @AshrafulMijan could you please make an example with a generic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you are facing is due to the fact that [`in` operator type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) works for string literals, but not for variables. This is also discussed in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64616994/typescript-type-narrowing-not-working-for-in-when-key-is-stored-in-a-variable).

The solution is to implement your own type guard which asserts that the value of the `key` variable is an actual key of the object in question.

```
type TypeA = { id: string; equipment: string; weight: string }
type TypeB = { id: string; equipment: string; material: string }
type TypeC = { id: string; equipment: string; width: string } 
type TypeD = { id: string; equipment: string; old: string } 
type TypeE = { id: string; equipment: string; recent: string }
type TypeF = { id: string; equipment: string; broken: string }

type Type = TypeA | TypeB | TypeC | TypeD | TypeE | TypeF;
type Key<U> = U extends U ? keyof U : never;

const items: Type[] = [
    { id: '11245', equipment: 'hammer', recent: 'yes' },
    { id: '11335', equipment: 'screwdriver', material: 'metal' }
];

const hasKey =
    <T extends object>(o: T, key: PropertyKey): key is keyof T => key in o;

const typeExclude =
    (key: Key<Type>, el: Type) => hasKey(el, key) ? el[key] : undefined

const arr = items.map(el => typeExclude('material', el) ? 'valid' : 'invalid');

console.log(arr);
```

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oG8oEsAmAuKAzsAE6YB2A5gNxQQCOArpmALYRnD5GmU0DuETBQAWnQiXIUoAXwBQoSLHgAhFOix5xParUbM2HLhN5QWAQ2ARSZgDZHtM+fCWQAwmow57kmvSat2MW4fKD4cYGFvShkoJ0U4SAARDw0onT99QLSaAHsbTWDo6ViFaASIAFEUry0QjIDDWpNiCABjLKapOVKXCAAxaoLjdL0GoOGaACNiHIBrdjTHOLLnVHKkAB9e1S3y9134ZIPIKuP+qmWoAGkIEAAeAFUAPjUH2gAPSzJsAig3gH4oPMQDkAGZ-KD4MgQABuVguslaOTIRCwlhYBHw5QA2gBdNTY2RQYnqGoAcgAjBSAEwAFgArGSADS6fwGMRk4RmFhsYjMqAtdqNMkgCAEMkyJlEkmeTSUikAZgVjJZ9XZ+DJBFaLT42FIcL5LPMlmsdigZLYwFsErkuIRSJRwCgXIINxAKGlxLuMA+Xx+UBykwAVm1gE8ABQ5LEs4H4AAKM0gxFAboAlPhgVhfsCwbAUC9M+QA-bkajShV3q0bAxsNBkJ6oOHY9dbt74E9VWbyqn886zK7buGIDYY7ce4Dh9jgfj8AxvhBQeQINhZIjS06zMRiGpMOiCAA6cxgIc2XvlyvV2vhi0WKyYa2d8fmmG2HASjXkF82N+pksovIQPuNg5BQ4absQv5AA)</sup>

In addition, I created a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) `Key<U>` that creates a union of the keys of all types that are part of the union `U`. This restricts the key parameter of your `typeExclude()` function to only accept known keys.

Answer (score 1):

I saw already solved this issue but i think this below code little bit cleaner and less code with my try using interface.

```js
interface IType {
  id: string;
  equipment: string;
  weight?: string;
  material?: string;
  width?: string;
  old?: string;
  recent?: string;
  broken?: string;
}

const items: IType[] = [
  { id: "11245", equipment: "hammer", recent: "yes" },
  { id: "11335", equipment: "screwdriver", material: "metal" },
];

const typeExclude = <T extends keyof IType>(key: T, obj: IType) => {
  return key in obj ? obj[key] : undefined;
};

const arr = items.map((el) =>
  typeExclude("material", el) ? "valid" : "invalid"
);

console.log(arr); // ['invalid', 'valid']
```